# Using React.js on multiple pages with Webpack

Tags: html, reactjs, webpack, babeljs

**Main question:** How do I stop this error: `Uncaught Error: Target container is not a DOM element` WHILE using multiple pages with different element tags.

This could be something simple in the structure that I overlooked while installing these tools: React, JSX, Babel, & Webpack. I've looked at every other related question on stackoverflow and elsewhere, but have not seen this exact situation.

**React.js Page 1 Example:**

```
import Navbar from '../../Common/Navbar';
import Info from './Info';
import Activity from './Activity';
import Activities from './Activities';

// Render Navbar
ReactDOM.render(<Navbar/>, document.querySelector('.navbar'));

// Render information
ReactDOM.render(<Info/>, document.querySelector('.left-panel'));

// Render activity
ReactDOM.render(<Activity/>, document.querySelector('.activity-panel'));

// Render activities
ReactDOM.render(<Activities/>, document.querySelector('.activities'));
```

**HTML Page 1 Example:**

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation"></nav>
<div class="container">

  <div class="left-panel"></div>

  <div class="activity-panel"></div>

  <div class="activities"></div>

</div>
```

**React.js Page 2 Example:**

```
import Navbar from '../../Common/Navbar';
import Info from './Info';
import Activity from './Activity';
import Activities from './Activities';

// Render Navbar
ReactDOM.render(<Navbar/>, document.querySelector('.navbar'));

// Render information
ReactDOM.render(<Main/>, document.querySelector('.main-page'));
```

**HTML Page 2 Example:**

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation"></nav>
<div class="container">

  <div class="main-page"></div>

</div>
```

**More Info:**

I know that this happens because the bundle.js file contains the React elements pointing to element tags that are not on the current HTML page. I'm fairly new with React.js & Webpack, so I could have missed something about formatting the code. I just need to know how to distinguish between pages when the JS is all bundled into one file.

Comment: You only do `ReactDOM.render()` for one parent component, say `App`, and call the other components in `App`. You will only have one `html` file and if you want multiple pages you can use `react-router`

Comment: May want to look into React portals:
https://reactjs.org/docs/portals.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's more common practice to just use `ReactDOM.render` for the root of your entire React component tree, but if you want to do it this way you could check if your `document.querySelector` calls actually found a DOM node or not before rendering.

```
import Navbar from '../../Common/Navbar';
import Info from './Info';
import Activity from './Activity';
import Activities from './Activities';
import Main from './Main';

// Render Navbar
const navbar = document.querySelector('.navbar');
if (navbar) {
  ReactDOM.render(<Navbar/>, navbar);
}

// Render information
const leftPanel = document.querySelector('.left-panel');
if (leftPanel) {
  ReactDOM.render(<Info/>, leftPanel);
}

// Render activity
const activityPanel = document.querySelector('.activity-panel');
if (activityPanel) {
  ReactDOM.render(<Activity/>, activityPanel);
}

// Render activities
const activities = document.querySelector('.activities');
if (activities)
  ReactDOM.render(<Activities/>, activities);
}

// Render information
const mainPage = document.querySelector('.main-page');
if (mainPage) {
  ReactDOM.render(<Main/>, mainPage);
}
```